# How to pass void** to a foreign function in Chez Scheme

Tags: chez-scheme

When a foreign function declared as

```
int open_db(char *path, Db **db)
```

creates internally an instance of Db and assigns the pointer to `*db`, what is the most efficient way to handle this from Chez Scheme?

The only thing I could come up with was allocating memory for a C-pointer using foreign-alloc, passing the address to it, copying the address and then immediately freeing this memory:

```
(define open_db (foreign-procedure "open_db" (string void*) int))

(define-record-type db (fields (mutable ptr)))

(define (open-db path)
(let ((pptr (foreign-alloc (foreign-sizeof 'void*))))
  (open_db path pptr)
    (let ((ptr (foreign-ref 'void* pptr 0)))
      (foreign-free pptr)
      (make-db ptr))))
```

Is there a way to avoid this temporary allocation of memory for the pointer?